# Transfer armatures keeping vertex weights

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting

I want to know if there's a way to transfer between two exact same armatures while keeping the weights, because I've already páinted the weights but there are some corrections that I want to make in the rig that I cannot do without spoiling the mesh. So my idea is to copy the armature and transfer the rig from one armature to the other which I'll make the bone positioning corrections. Is there another way that I 'm not aware of?